# Diferença entre tamalho de string em C Padrão e C++

Tags: c, array, c++, string, buffer

Compilei o código abaixo em C Padrão e em C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char string[5] = "hello";

int main(void)
{

   printf("string tem %lu bytes\n", sizeof(string));

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      printf("string[%d]: %d \n", i, string[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Em C Padrão ele compila normalmente, mas em C++ ele dá erro ao compilar.

**Qual a diferença entre o C e o C++ para dar esse erro?**

output no C++:

```
entradas.cpp:4:18: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
    4 | char string[5] = "hello";
      |                  ^~~~~~~
```

O IntelliSense do vs codedá o aviso:

```
um valor de tipo "const char [6]" não pode ser utilizado para inicializar  uma entidade do tipo "char [5]"C/C++(144)
```

Complementando, compilei sem problemas em C padrão, e em c++ utilizando a declaração da variável dessa forma:

```
char string[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

Usei no teste o vsCode (code runner) e o Replit.

Comment: Note que em um `char[6]` o número de posições/elementos/itens/casas é 6 mesmo. A posição/índice vai de 0 até 5, que é aonde vai o `\0`, ou seja, cabem até 5 letras nas casas restantes.

Comment: Por que então, utilizando os exemplos no final da pergunta, em C e em C++ separando as letras em caracteres, compilo sem mensagem de erro?

Comment: A pergunta não parece muito coerente, o código mostra uma coisa, as mensagens mostram coisas que não podem aparecer nesse código. Nem sabemos de fato oque está acontecendo.